# Deploy from Maven to JFrog Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have downloaded and installed JFrog Artifactory community edition on a virtual machine.

from my host machine, I am able to see the JFrog admin console when I do http://build.local:8081/. I created a test user in Artifactory and granted the user all the rights

[image]

On my host machine I create a java maven project. My POM.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abhi</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>MyJFrog</id>
            <name>MyJFrogArtifactory</name>
            <url>http://build.local:8081/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Changed my ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <username>testuser</username>
    <password>testpassword</password>
    <id>MyJFrog</id>
  </server>
</servers>
```

But still when I do `mvn deploy -e` I get error

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project HelloWorld: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.abhi:HelloWorld:jar:1.0-20151013.153708-1 from/to MyJFrog (http://build.local:8081/libs-snapshot-local): Access denied to: http://build.local:8081/libs-snapshot-local/com/abhi/HelloWorld/1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld-1.0-20151013.153708-1.jar, **ReasonPhrase: Forbidden.**
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
```

I did lot of research on internet. most people cited proxy issues. but I am on a single machine. the build.local is an entry I made in my hosts file and point to the IP of the VM. So there is no proxy involved here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. My distributionManagement setting above is wrong.

In the JFrog Artifactory go into Artifacts -> libs snapshot local -> Set me up

Here you will see the right setting for distribution management.

[image]

Comment: This is valid answer but on this [link](http://kishore.chintoju.com/blog/2012/12/deploy-to-artifactory-remote-repository-using-maven.html) there is more detail of `pom.xml` and Maven ecosystem